# How do I save an ExternalId in Google Admin SDK?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client

I am able to create a user successfully, and I'm attempting to save an ExternalId when I create the user.

```
Dim _localId As directory_v1.Data.UserExternalId = New directory_v1.Data.UserExternalId()
_localId.Type = "custom"
_localId.CustomType = "LocalID"
_localId.Value = "123456"
newUser.ExternalIds = _localId
```

however, when I subsequently get that user back from Google, the ExternalId object is empty on the User object.  I'm assuming that the way I am attempting to create the ExternalId is wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860653/how-to-update-a-users-externalid-using-java/27866890#27866890

Comment: That response is for Java, which is fine, except that the .net version of the code does not have a `setExternalIDs() function call.  I can't get this to work.