# How do I get valid JSON back for a UserOrganization object

Tags: gson, google-admin-sdk

The JSON being returned as a representation of a UserOrganization object is invalid, and the Gson parser throws an exception when trying to convert it into a UserOrganization object.

For example, I added a UserOrganization with a type of work and the Org Title set to TitleValue.  The JSON passed was {title=TitleValue, type=work}.  No exception is thrown.  Then when I try to retrieve that the JSON returned from Google is {title=TitleValue, customType=}.  There is no type value, and custom type is blank.  The specific exception is JsonSyntaxException with a message of "Expected literal value at line 1 column 31".

Am I not creating the UserOrganization object correctly?  How do I get valid JSON back?

Comment: Try sending the request in oauth play ground, in that tool you can build your JSON along with sending request to google API. Here is the link https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/. Also, check this link on how to use oauth playground http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860653/how-to-update-a-users-externalid-using-java/27866890#27866890

Comment: I should note that my example text was just pulled from calling toString on my UserOrganization java object, not really JSON.  The same is true of the return string.  Regarding the playground, I already tried that.  Even using the API Explorer and sending the correct JSON (not that stuff I showed above...) the type field gets stripped and then calling user.get returns the empty customType field.  In looking at what FlashPanel did, for example, I see they bypassed trying to use type and just send a customType of 'other'.  Has anyone successfully set a type of work?