# Google Script/Sheet unsure how to pull information for the Employee information section from the user profile such as Employee ID & Job Title

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that is able to populate a sheet with the info required but I am unsure how to retrieve the data from the Employee Information section in the user profile. I would like the below 4 items, what am I missing??  I have also taken a look at the [Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) but have had no luck in adding externalIds[]    please help point in the right direction if you can

1. Employee ID
2. Job Title
3. Type of Employee
4. Department

```html
function listAllUsers() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Users');
  sheet.getRange(1, 8).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy"));
 
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  n = 0;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'domain.co.uk',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        sheet.getRange(n + i + 2, 1).setValue(user.name.fullName);      
        sheet.getRange(n + i + 2, 2).setValue(user.name.givenName); 
        sheet.getRange(n + i + 2, 3).setValue(user.name.familyName); 
        sheet.getRange(n + i + 2, 4).setValue(user.primaryEmail);  
        sheet.getRange(n + i + 2, 5).setValue(user.orgUnitPath);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    n+=100;
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want the following data:

[image] [image]

Both `externalIds` and `organizations` are arrays. They allow for multiple sets of data for the same person.

Assuming your database has just one set for each person, you could try:

`user.externalIds[0].value`

`user.organizations[0].title`

`user.organizations[0].type`

`user.organizations[0].department`

PS: I have not used this API, and these suggestions are based on my reading of the docs. Let me know if it works. Best of luck.

---

PPS: I would also suggest sending all the data to the sheet in one go to minimize calls to the sheet

```
sheet.getRange(n + i + 2, 1, 1, 5).setValues([user.name.fullName, user.name.givenName, user.name.familyName, user.primaryEmail, user.orgUnitPath]);
```

It may be even more efficient to put all user data in an array and post to the sheet in one go.

And you could also avoid calling `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` for each user. Best to do it once at the end of posting data.

---

### Edit

To avoid fails from missing `externalId`, you could try:

```
  if (user.externalIds) {
    var extID = user.externalIds[0].value;
  } else {
    extID = null;
  }
```

and then post the `extId` to the sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I receive the error below when trying  user.externalIds[0].value

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined


I have not looked at optimizing the script yet with your other suggestions

Comment: The error suggests that `externalIds` does not exist. This may be an issue for a specific user or for all users. Try looking at the data by logging it: `Logger.log([i, user.externalIds])`.

Comment: The field won't exist unless the user has it. You can check at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860653/how-to-update-a-users-externalid-using-java) to add it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to suggest a way to avoid failure from the occasional missing `exertnalIds`. You could use the same idea if the company details may be missing for some users.